# How do I open an image from the internet in PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, urllib2

I would like to find the dimensions of an image on the internet. I tried using

```
from PIL import Image
import urllib2 as urllib
fd = urllib.urlopen("http://a/b/c")
im = Image.open(fd)
im.size
```

as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6014074/159388), but I get the error message

```
addinfourl instance has no attribute 'seek'
```

I checked and objects returned by `urllib2.urlopen(url)` do not seem to have a seek method according to `dir`.

So, what do I have to do to be able to load an image from the Internet into PIL?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You might consider using [`io.BytesIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/io.html#buffered-streams) for [forward compatibility](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/forward+compatibility).
The StringIO and cStringIO modules do not exist in Python 3.

```
from PIL import Image
import urllib2 as urllib
import io

fd = urllib.urlopen("http://a/b/c")
image_file = io.BytesIO(fd.read())
im = Image.open(image_file)
```

Comment: I would suggest using [`tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile) with a max size to avoid unintended memory exhaustion.

Answer (score 14):

Using Python `requests`:

```
from PIL import Image
from StringIO import StringIO
import requests

r = requests.get("http://a/b/c")
im = Image.open(StringIO(r.content))
im.size
```

Comment: Though this answer is different than the others, it doesn't solve the actual problem any differently than jdi's answer. It still wraps the stream in `StringIO`.

Comment: This worked a treat for a Docker image that didn't have urllib2 but had requests. Thanks for posting an alternative.

Comment: Fix for ImportError: `from io import StringIO` for Python 3```

Answer (score 10):

This [pull-request](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/1151#issuecomment-87346557) adds support for stream-handling native to Pillow (the friendly PIL fork) and should be available from version 2.8.0. This allows the simpler opening remote files with [urllib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html):

```
from PIL import Image
import urllib2
Image.open(urllib2.urlopen(url))
```

...or using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)
```

As [mentioned by mjpieters on the PR](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/1151#issuecomment-87346557) requests does not automatically decode `gzip` responses, so if you're downloading images that have been further compressed for whatever reason you must set `decode_content=True` on the response object before accessing `.raw`.

```
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
response.raw.decode_content = True
image = Image.open(response.raw)
```

Answer (score 8):

Using your same example, just use StringIO to wrap the buffer into a proper file-like object:

```
from PIL import Image
import urllib2 as urllib
from StringIO import StringIO

fd = urllib.urlopen("http://a/b/c")
im = Image.open(StringIO(fd.read()))
im.size
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`urllib` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib#urllib.urlopen) mentions that an object returned by `urlopen` doesn't support `seek` operation.

> This module provides a high-level interface for fetching data across
>   the World Wide Web. In particular, the urlopen() function is similar
>   to the built-in function open(), but accepts Universal Resource
>   Locators (URLs) instead of filenames. Some restrictions apply — it can
>   only open URLs for reading, and no seek operations are available.

However, the [`PIL.open`](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm#open) function explicitly requires it.

> **open**
>
> Image.open(infile) => image
>
> Image.open(infile, mode) => image
>
> Opens and identifies the given image file. This is a lazy operation;
>   the actual image data is not read from the file until you try to
>   process the data (call the load method to force loading). If the mode
>   argument is given, it must be "r".
>
> You can use either a string (representing the filename) or a file
>   object. In the latter case, **the file object must implement read, seek,
>   and tell methods**, and be opened in binary mode.

Try using `cStringIO` module that converts a string into a file-like object.

```
from PIL import Image
import urllib2 as urllib
import cStringIO

fd = urllib.urlopen("http://a/b/c")
image_file = cStringIO.StringIO(fd.read())
im = Image.open(image_file)
im.size
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is 4 years ago, but it's still on top in Google.In Python3,
we have simple solution.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
img =Image.open(urlopen('http://dl.iplaypython.com/images/banner336x280.jpg'))
new_img =img.resize((300,500),Image.ANTIALIAS)
new_img.save('url.jpg','jpeg')
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Using requests library and and get output as Bytes

```
import requests
import io

response = requests.get("https://i.imgur.com/ExdKOOz.png")
image_bytes = io.BytesIO(response.content)
```