# ImageFont from font data or URL

Tags: python, django, fonts, amazon-s3, python-imaging-library

I would like to know how to use an ImageFont instance from an URL or font data in Python.
The font file is stored on an Amazon S3 instance as static data and I need to use it to generate an image with PIL.

ImageFont.load() function only accepts a filename so I feel quite locked.

As deep as I could dig in the code, it was the _imagingft.so library's getfont() function which was taking the filename as a parameter and I quite don't feel like modifying this library. ;)

Thanks for your help !

Comment: No, actually what I was looking for is how to get a PIL ImageFont instance providing a the font file or a URL rather than the filename.
The problem is that PIL looks for the font file on the hard disk and can't just take the font file as data in a parameter or from a URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people interested in the solution, refer to [this post](https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/pull/202).

Edit : It has been merged to master now, enjoy !

Answer (score 1):

Example can be found into [the test in Pillow repository](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/Tests/test_imagefont.py):

```
from PIL import ImageFont
from io import BytesIO

def _font_as_bytes():
    with open(FONT_PATH, 'rb') as f:
        font_bytes = BytesIO(f.read())
    return font_bytes

ImageFont.truetype(_font_as_bytes(), FONT_SIZE)
```

And see also: [How do I open an image from the internet in PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020657/how-do-i-open-an-image-from-the-internet-in-pil)