# Using pandas read_csv with zip compression

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use `read_csv` in pandas to read a zipped file from an FTP server. The zip file contains just one file, as is required.

Here's my code:

```
pd.read_csv('ftp://ftp.fec.gov/FEC/2016/cn16.zip', compression='zip')
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute 'seek'
```

I get this error in both pandas 18.1 and 19.0. Am I missing something, or could this be a bug?

Comment: How many files exist in this zip file?

Comment: There's only one file, as required

Comment: seem `zip` needs `seek()` to move file pointer but internet stream (`http`, `ftp`, etc.) is not real file and doesn't have function `seek()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I'm not completely sure why you get the error, you can get around it by opening the url using `urllib2` and writing the data to an in-memory binary stream, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12020860/6779606). In addition, we have to specify the correct separator, or else we would receive another error.

```
import io
import urllib2 as urllib
import pandas as pd

r = urllib.urlopen('ftp://ftp.fec.gov/FEC/2016/cn16.zip')
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(r.read()), compression='zip', sep='|', header=None)
```

As far as the error itself, I think pandas is trying to use seek on the "zip file" prior to downloading the url contents (so it's not really a zip file), which would result in that error.

Answer (score 14):

pandas now supports to load data straight from zip or other compressed files to DataFrame.

> compression : {‘infer’, ‘gzip’, ‘bz2’, ‘zip’, ‘xz’, None}, default ‘infer’
>
> For on-the-fly decompression of on-disk data. If ‘infer’ and
> filepath_or_buffer is path-like, then detect compression from the
> following extensions: ‘.gz’, ‘.bz2’, ‘.zip’, or ‘.xz’ (otherwise no
> decompression). If using ‘zip’, the ZIP file must contain only one
> data file to be read in. Set to None for no decompression.
>
> New in version 0.18.1: support for ‘zip’ and ‘xz’ compression.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("path_to_file.zip")
# or
df = pd.read_csv("path_to_file.zip", compression="zip")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
header = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0.1',}
remotezip = requests.get(url, headers=header)
root = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(remotezip.content))
for name in root.namelist():
            df = pd.read_csv(root.open(name))
```

Taken from my own blog post:
[Read zipped csv files in python pandas without downloading zipfile](http://learnvinod.blogspot.in/2017/08/read-zipped-csv-files-in-python-pandas.html)